# E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Form1' - Out of Nowhere

Tags: delphi

I've been dabbling with Delphi again on a VM for the first time in a long time, and am currently working on importing JSON. However, all of a sudden (no doubt I've removed or corrupted something) I'm unable to compile the project.

Every time I try, I get the message **E003 Undeclared identifier: 'Form1'** and the editor snaps to the program file **Project1**, resting on the `Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);` line.

I've attached my `unit1.pas`, which is where the form sits, as well as the seemingly relevant other files. Please help! What have I done / removed?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Xml.xmldom, Xml.XMLIntf,
  Xml.XMLDoc, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL,
  IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, inifiles,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

const
  GstrAPIKey = 'removed this :)';

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    XMLDocument1: TXMLDocument;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    rgrp_Home: TRadioGroup;
    cbx_Report: TComboBox;
    cbx_Charts: TComboBox;
    sb_Main: TStatusBar;
    dt_From: TDateTimePicker;
    dt_To: TDateTimePicker;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    lbl_DF: TLabel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    edt_Search: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button4: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    Reports: TTabSheet;
    Charts: TTabSheet;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure rgrp_HomeClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cbx_ReportChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure pnl_ReportsClick(Sender: TObject);
  private

    { Private declarations }
    procedure SetJSON(const Value : string);
    function GetJSON : string;
  public
          shortdateformat: string;
    { Public declarations }
    property JSON: string read GetJSON write SetJSON;

  end;

var
  strCommID : string;
  GstrPath,
  GstrCommID,
  GstrURL : string;

implementation

type
    TCareNote = (
                  CareNoteID  = 1,
                  CareNoteExtID = 2,
                  ADLName = 3,
                  FlagsText = 4,
                  Note = 5,
                  AnswerType = 6,
                  Fragment = 7,
                  RemedialText = 8,
                  Details = 9,
                  ServiceUserID = 10,
                  ServiceUser = 11,
                  ServiceUserLastName = 12,
                  ServiceUserForenames = 13,
                  ServiceUserDOB = 14,
                  ServiceUserLocation = 15,
                  WorkerID = 16,
                  Worker = 17,
                  VoidedByWorker = 18,
                  _supercedestack = 19,
                  SupercededbyWorker = 20,
                  WorkerLastName = 21,
                  DisplayonShiftHO = 22,
                  WorkerInitials = 23,
                  SliderData = 24,
                  SliderDate2 = 25,
                  SliderIcons = 26,
                  DateDone = 27,
                  DateDoneSU = 28,
                  Duration = 29,
                  DurationInt = 30,
                  ActionIconID = 31,
                  mraCareOrder = 32,
                  WasPlanned = 33,
                  qrVerified = 34,
                  qrData = 35,
                  nfcVerified = 36,
                  inVerified = 37
                );





{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.GetJSON : string;
begin
  Result := Memo1.Lines.Text;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetJSON(const Value: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text := Value;
end;

{*********************************************}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
{*********************************************}
var
  s : tmemorystream;
begin
  idhttp1.HandleRedirects := TRUE;
  s := tmemorystream.Create;
  idhttp1.ReadTimeout := 30000;
  idhttp1.IOHandler := idssl;
  IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
  IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  idhttp1.Get(GstrURL,S);
  s.Position := 0;
  memo1.Lines.loadfromstream(s);
end;

{*********************************************}
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);


{*********************************************}
var
  IniFile : TIniFile;
  strURL : string;
  strRep : string;
  strDateFrom,
  strDateTo : string;
begin
  try
      IniFile := TIniFile.Create(GstrPath+'\config.ini');
      GstrURL := IniFile.ReadString('URL','path','Error');
      GstrURL := GstrURL+GstrAPIKey;
      GstrURL := GstrURL+'/ReportsAndChartsApi/Get/';
      case cbx_Report.ItemIndex of
        -1  :  ;
        0   : begin
                  strRep := 'CareNotesReport';
              end;
        1   : begin
                  strRep := 'AccidentsReport';
              end;
        2   : begin
                  strRep := 'IncidentsReport';
              end;
        3   : begin
                  strRep := 'FallsReport';

              end;
        4   : begin
                  strRep := 'InfectionsReport';
              end;
        5   : begin
                  strRep := 'WoundSummaryReport';
              end;
        end;

      //Dates to and from for the report...
      strDateFrom := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',dt_From.Date);
      GstrURL := GstrURL + strRep +'?DateFrom='+strDateFrom;

      strDateTo := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',dt_To.Date);
      GstrURL := GstrURL +'&DateTo='+strDateTo;

      if (Length(edt_Search.Text) > 0) and (cbx_Report.Itemindex <> 3) then
      begin
            GstrURL := GstrURL + '&SearchText='+edt_Search.Text;
      end;

      //Community IDs
      GstrURL := GstrURL + '&CommunityID='+GstrCommID;

      //if there is anything in the search text box...

      //showmessage(strurl);
  finally

  end;
  //edt_URL.Text := IniFile.ReadString('URL','Path')+DateToStr(dt_From.DateTime)+
end;

{*************************************************}
procedure TForm1.cbx_ReportChange(Sender: TObject);
{*************************************************}
begin
if (cbx_Report.ItemIndex = 3) then
        edt_Search.ReadOnly := TRUE
else
        edt_Search.ReadOnly := FALSE;
end;

{*******************************************}
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
{*******************************************}
begin
  //find the path of the executable to make sure the right config file is used
  GstrPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.Exename);
end;

procedure TForm1.pnl_ReportsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

{***********************************************}
procedure TForm1.rgrp_HomeClick(Sender: TObject);
{***********************************************}
var
  Inifile : TIniFile;
  strChoice :string;
begin
    try
      Inifile := TIniFile.Create(GstrPath+'\config.ini'); //create the inifile link
      strChoice := rgrp_Home.Items[rgrp_Home.ItemIndex];
      if Inifile.SectionExists('Community') then
        if IniFile.ValueExists('Community',strChoice) then
        begin
            GstrCommID := IniFile.ReadString('Community',strChoice,'');

            sb_Main.Panels[0].Text := 'Current Home: '+strChoice;
            sb_Main.Panels[1].Text := 'Comm ID: '+ GstrCommID;
            IniFile.Destroy;
        end;
    finally
      if GstrCommID = '' then MessageDLG(strChoice+' is not yet on PCS',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);

    end;

end;

end.`



object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 669
  ClientWidth = 508
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poDesigned
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object lbl_DF: TLabel
    Left = 130
    Top = 119
    Width = 54
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Date From:'
  end
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 233
    Top = 119
    Width = 42
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Date To:'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 336
    Top = 119
    Width = 58
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Search Text'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 185
    Top = 165
    Width = 145
    Height = 49
    Caption = 'Fetch Information'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 19
    Top = 247
    Width = 481
    Height = 132
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object rgrp_Home: TRadioGroup
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 105
    Height = 177
    Caption = 'Homes'
    Items.Strings = (
      'Croston'
      'Hall'
      'Magnolia'
      'Manor'
      'Croft'
      'Lodge'
      'Hollow')
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = rgrp_HomeClick
  end
  object sb_Main: TStatusBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 650
    Width = 508
    Height = 19
    Panels = <
      item
        Text = 'Current Home:'
        Width = 200
      end
      item
        Text = 'Comm ID:'
        Width = 400
      end
      item
        Width = 50
      end>
  end
  object dt_From: TDateTimePicker
    Left = 130
    Top = 138
    Width = 97
    Height = 21
    Date = 43744.000000000000000000
    Time = 0.867717511573573600
    TabOrder = 4
  end
  object dt_To: TDateTimePicker
    Left = 233
    Top = 138
    Width = 97
    Height = 21
    Date = 43744.000000000000000000
    Time = 0.867717511573573600
    TabOrder = 5
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 19
    Top = 220
    Width = 481
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 6
  end
  object edt_Search: TEdit
    Left = 336
    Top = 138
    Width = 95
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 7
  end
  object Button4: TButton
    Left = 398
    Top = 82
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Create URL'
    TabOrder = 8
    OnClick = Button4Click
  end
  object PageControl1: TPageControl
    Left = 130
    Top = 51
    Width = 255
    Height = 62
    ActivePage = Reports
    TabOrder = 9
    object Reports: TTabSheet
      Caption = 'Reports'
      object Label3: TLabel
        Left = 20
        Top = 12
        Width = 72
        Height = 13
        Caption = 'Choose Report'
      end
      object cbx_Report: TComboBox
        Left = 99
        Top = 9
        Width = 145
        Height = 21
        Style = csDropDownList
        TabOrder = 0
        OnChange = cbx_ReportChange
        Items.Strings = (
          'Care Notes'
          'Accidents'
          'Incidents'
          'Falls'
          'Infections'
          'Wounds')
      end
    end
    object Charts: TTabSheet
      Caption = 'Charts'
      ImageIndex = 1
      ExplicitLeft = 0
      ExplicitTop = 0
      ExplicitWidth = 0
      ExplicitHeight = 0
      object Label4: TLabel
        Tag = 10
        Left = 20
        Top = 13
        Width = 66
        Height = 13
        Caption = 'Choose Chart'
      end
      object cbx_Charts: TComboBox
        Left = 99
        Top = 9
        Width = 145
        Height = 21
        Style = csDropDownList
        TabOrder = 0
        Items.Strings = (
          'Bowel Movements'
          'Fluids'
          'Hygiene'
          'Bedrails Checks'
          'Mattress Check'
          'Repositioning'
          'Emotional Support')
      end
    end
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 164
    Top = 10
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button2'
    TabOrder = 10
  end
  object Memo2: TMemo
    Left = 19
    Top = 432
    Width = 481
    Height = 193
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo2')
    TabOrder = 11
  end
  object Button3: TButton
    Left = 216
    Top = 401
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button3'
    TabOrder = 12
  end
  object XMLDocument1: TXMLDocument
    Left = 896
    Top = 8
  end
  object IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP
    AllowCookies = True
    HandleRedirects = True
    ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication = False
    ProxyParams.ProxyPort = 0
    Request.ContentLength = -1
    Request.ContentRangeEnd = -1
    Request.ContentRangeStart = -1
    Request.ContentRangeInstanceLength = -1
    Request.Accept = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    Request.BasicAuthentication = False
    Request.UserAgent = 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)'
    Request.Ranges.Units = 'bytes'
    Request.Ranges = <>
    HTTPOptions = [hoForceEncodeParams]
    Left = 944
    Top = 8
  end
  object IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
    MaxLineAction = maException
    Port = 0
    DefaultPort = 0
    SSLOptions.Mode = sslmUnassigned
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
    Left = 984
    Top = 8
  end
end`
```

Comment: The error message tells you the necessary information. How do you read it? What do you think it means?

Comment: Sometimes it's easy to see a very simple message, like "undeclared identifier", and totally miss what it means. Well, I do anyway lol

Comment: So my message to you is to spend time thinking about what could cause that error. To look at the documentation for the error. Yes, error messages have documentation. In this case the cause of your undeclared identifier was simply that the identifier was not declared. It's very easy to glaze over with error messages. But often, not always, they will lead you to the issue.

Comment: Yes. Someone went one better with their message, and actually pointed out the error for me. Thanks.

Comment: I guess whether or not this is better depends on whether the goal here is to solve one problem at a time, or whether the goal is to learn techniques to enable you to solve many problems in the future. That's all I was trying to say.

Comment: Noted. A combination of both inputs would've been the best. I do appreciate the help. I studied Delphi in 2002 and dabbled in it now and again as a side hobby until about 2009 (using 2002 methods). I've picked it up again to take an API link from a piece of monitoring software we use to parse the JSON it accesses, but elements of this are very new to me. I was certain I'd added something wrong, or corrupted a file somewhere. All's well that ends well, but I'm still not there with the JSON parsing!

Comment: Well, I added my comment 4 hours after Uwe answered. It was meant to be in addition to, not instead of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have (probably by accident) removed the `Form1: TForm1` declaration in the interface var section.

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;  // <<--- Should be there, but is missing
  strCommID : string;
  GstrPath,
  GstrCommID,
  GstrURL : string;
```

Comment: I usually remove all form variables in the form units and declare them in the project file. So there is also a possibility that it was removed from that position.

Comment: I am an IDIOT! I've been looking and looking, thinking well I reference it here and there. I never thought it would be something so simple, and even looked at other pas examples but didn't see it. Thank you very much. It now loads again. D'OH!